# Reducing and Summing Array of Objects Based on Key

Tags: javascript, object, coffeescript, reduce

Suppose that I had the following array of objects in CoffeeScript:

```
data = [
  {date: "04/27/2017", number: 1},
  {date: "04/28/2017", number: 2},
  {date: "04/27/2017", number: 3},
  {date: "04/29/2017", number: 4},
  {date: "04/29/2017", number: 5}
]
```

I want sum the number values by the date values, creating this new array:

```
new_data = [
  {date: "04/27/2017", number: 4},
  {date: "04/28/2017", number: 2},
  {date: "04/29/2017", number: 9}
]
```

It seems reasonable to use the `reduce` method, something like:

```
new_data = data.reduce (x, y) ->
  some logic
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out/find a way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want in 2 steps

1. Group values to a single object

   ```
   let reducer = (acc, cur) => {
     if (acc[cur.date] === undefined)
       acc[cur.date] = cur.number
     else
       acc[cur.date] = acc[cur.date] + cur.number
     return acc;
   }

   let grouped = data.reduce(reducer, {});
   ```
2. Map object to an Array

   ```
   Object.keys(counterRes).map((date) => { return { date, number: grouped[date] } })
   ```

The final result is what you are after.